# Binding dropdownlist without refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am adding Category using jquery/ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin.aspx/SaveCategory",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "kategorija": kategorija }),
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.d == "true") {
                //console.log(kategorija);
                kopce.removeClass("btn-default");
                kopce.addClass("btn-success");
                kopce.html("Dodadeno!");
            }

        }
```

At the WebMethod on the server **SaveCategory** i have this code, also here i am calling a function for populating the dropdown.

```
var context = new CategoryEntities();

            var t = new Category //Make sure you have a table called test in DB
            {
               // CategoryId = Guid(),
                CategoryName = kategorija,
            };

            context.Categories.Add(t);
            context.SaveChanges();
            FillDropDown();
            string result = "true";

            return result;
```

My function for populating dropdown :

```
public void FillDropDown()
        {
            var context = new CategoryEntities();

            var category = (from c in context.Categories
                            select new { c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName }).ToList();

            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            DropDownList1.DataSource = category;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();     

        }
```

But function for populating a dropdown does not fire when SaveCategory function is called.

I want to bind/refresh dropdown when category is added. Some help ?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What you mean by `FillDropDown` does not fire? If `SaveCategory` method is fired then `FillDropDown` method should be triggered too. Check if category is actually getting saved in DB.

Comment: Category saves perfectly. But dropdownlist is binding just on page refresh. 
So if i add a category, then refresh, everything works fine. The problem is how to populate dropdown without refresh ...

Comment: You can append the new category in your JS code itself.

Comment: Bind dropdown when save is done. Any idea ?

Comment: Yeah, instead of returning `true` from your WebMethod you can return the `CategoryId` to the client and you already have `CategoryName` at the client. Now simply append the new `<option>` in your dropdownlist. If you are not sure how to add new item, Search how to bind\append items to dropdownlist, you will get many answers.

Comment: Can i use jquery append here, in this dropdown ? : 
                   `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: Yes absolutely, Please note your browser only understands HTML and your asp.net `asp:DropDownList ` control is rendered as `select` html with `<option>` tags so you can use jQuery append to add `<option>` tag.

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thanks for your help.